# Problema com Segmentation Fault

Tags: c

Estou criando um programa que simula um campo minado,e a opção numero 1 deve pegar de um arquivo do computador uma matriz (que contem pontos(para aonde não tem bomba) e asteriscos(para aonde tem bomba) e copiar para uma matriz que vou alocando dinamicamente na função leitura.

Estou tendo um problema de *segmentation fault* e não estou conseguindo detectar o erro, ficaria grato pela ajuda, segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char** leitura(char* nome)//Declaracao de funcao que aloca a matriz
{
    FILE* ponteiro;
    int i = 0,j = 1, k ,l;
    char** campo = NULL;
    char carac;

    ponteiro = fopen("nome", "w");

    while(!feof(ponteiro))
    {
        i++;
        campo = (char**) realloc(campo, i * sizeof(char*));     

        while(fscanf(ponteiro, "%c", &carac) != '\n')
        {
            campo[j - 1] = (char*) realloc(campo[j - 1], j * sizeof(char));
            campo[i - 1][j - 1] = carac;
            j++;    
        }
    }

    for(k = 0; k < i; k++)
    {
        for(l = 0; l < j; l++)
        {
            printf("%c", campo[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(ponteiro);

    return campo; //Retorno da matriz alocada dinamicamente
}

int main (void)
{
    int tamanho = 0, linha = 0, coluna = 0;
    char* nome = NULL;
    char** retornoCampo = NULL;
    size_t tam;
    getline(&nome, &tam, stdin); //Funcao para adquirir o nome do arquivo
    int i, j;

    nome[strlen(nome) - 1] = '\0';

    int opcao = 0;

    scanf("%d", &opcao);

    switch(opcao) //Opcoes a serem escolhidas
    {
        case 1: //Leitura

            retornoCampo = leitura(nome);

            break;
        case 2: //Inicializacao do tabuleiro
            break;
        case 3: //Acao do usuario
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aqui o código compilou e rodou normalmente. O _segmentation fault_ só acontece quando eu digito um numero/texto e depois digito '1'.  Se eu digitar '1' primero e depois inserir um texto/numero, o programa encerra. De qualquer forma, o programa permite escrever uma opção  duas vezes.

Comment: Aqui eu inverti e continua com segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vejo dois problemas:

O primeiro, é nas várias chamadas ao comando `realloc`: quando o tamanho da região de memória é aumentado, `realloc` realiza a cópia da memória que já estava alocada para a nova região de memória (se é que esta é efetivamente uma nova região de memória), mas não realiza a inicialização os bytes que foram alocados a mais.

Assim, na linha: `campo = (char**) realloc(campo, i * sizeof(char*));` é alocado uma região de memória de tamanho `sizeof(char*)` (quando `i == 0`), e esta região contém lixo de memória, já que você não a inicializa.

Quando a chamada `campo[j - 1] = (char*) realloc(campo[j - 1], j * sizeof(char));` é executada, ele tenta realocar memória para um ponteiro que aponta para lixo de memória, podendo assim causar a falha de segmentação.

Outro problema ocorre nas iterações sub-sequentes da linha:

```
campo[j - 1] = (char*) realloc(campo[j - 1], j * sizeof(char));
```

*Para facilitar a explicação, vamos ignorar o primeiro problema, e fazer de conta que o `realloc` irá fazer o serviço direitinho no primeiro problema levantado.*

Quando `j == 1`, `campo[j - 1]` será alocado corretamente com o tamanho `sizeof(char)`.

Na próxima linha, ainda quando `j == 1`, você faz uma atribuição à posição `[0][0]` através do comando: `campo[i - 1][j - 1] = carac;`, e em seguida incrementa `j`.

Na segunda iteração (`i == 1`, `j == 2`), o `realloc` é feito sobre o elemento `campo[1]`, pois `j - 1 == 1`. Mas repare que a quantidade de posições da variável `campo` ainda é 1, e portanto apenas o índice `0` é válido, causando novamente segmentation fault. Ou seja, você esta redimensionando a posição errada da variável `campo`. Para resolver isto basta trocar `j` por `i` na linha deste realloc, ficando:

```
campo[i - 1] = (char*) realloc(campo[i - 1], j * sizeof(char));
```

Ressalto que estes dois problemas ocorrem simultaneamente e devem ser corrigidos. Tente evidar `realloc`, ele é um comando muito caro para ser executado.

Podem haver outros problemas, mas estes foram os que notei mais facilmente.

Espero ter ajudado, e não ficado muito confusa a explicação.